# Printing Coordinate Points to file in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, game-physics

In this project, there exists a randomly moving object whose coordinates I must print to file. In order to do so, I created a function named PrintPoints(). However, I do not know where to call PrintPoints(), as if I call it in the Update() method, it produces long and ridiculous output, which I believe is because Update() runs for each frame. I simply need to run Update() and print the coordinates after the object is finished moving (the very end of the program).

How do I achieve this?

Thank you very much!

PS: Below is my code

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

bool hasArrived;
private float movementDuration = 2.0f;
private float waitBeforeMoving = 2.0f;
private Vector3[] v = new Vector3[20];

//StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("output.txt",true);
void Update()
{
    if (!hasArrived)
    {
        hasArrived = true;
        StartCoroutine(MoveToPoints());
    }
}

private IEnumerator MoveToPoints()
{


    for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
    {
        float timer = 0.0f;
        Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
        float x = RandomNum(timer);
        float y = RandomNum(x);
        float z = RandomNum(y);
        v[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);

        while (timer < movementDuration)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            float t = timer / movementDuration;
            t = t * t * t * (t * (6f * t - 15f) + 10f);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, v[i], t);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitBeforeMoving);
    }
}

void PrintPoints()
{
    //path of file
    string path = Application.dataPath + "/Player.txt";
    //create file if nonexistent
    if(!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, "The player blob visited these random coordinates: \n\n");
    }

    foreach(Vector3 vector in v)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(path, "(" + vector.x + ", " + vector.y + ", " + vector.z + ")\n\n");
    }


}

float RandomNum(float lastRandNum)
{
    //Random value range can be changed in the future if necessary
    float randNum = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
    return System.Math.Abs(randNum - lastRandNum) < double.Epsilon ? RandomNum(randNum) : randNum;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this program you must call PrintPoints() once, after the call of MoveToPoints(), because you print all Points in the vector.
A better way is, you print only one point at a call of PrintPoints. I would give the Point to print as Argument to the method, like:

```
void PrintPoint(Vector3 vector)
{
   //path of file
  string path = Application.dataPath + "/Player.txt";
  //create file if nonexistent
  if(!File.Exists(path))
  {
    File.WriteAllText(path, "The player blob visited these random coordinates: \n\n");
  }

  File.AppendAllText(path, "(" + vector.x + ", " + vector.y + ", " + vector.z + ")\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your reply. I put the print point inside MoveToPoints() at the end. Unfortunately, this was the output.

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces a long file mostly filled with (0,0,0) and repeated coordinates.

Comment: Are you shure, you create new random coordinates with each call of Random.Range(....)?

Comment: Well yes, because the ball is moving to different coordinates in each run.

Comment: Is there a better solution, though?

Answer (score 0):

Update() runs every frame, as you said. If you only want the MoveToPoints() method to be called once, you can call it in the Start()-method instead. If you do so you can then call the PrintPoints()-method after the call of the MoveToPoints()-method.

This would look something like this:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    private float movementDuration = 2.0f;
    private float waitBeforeMoving = 2.0f;
    private Vector3[] v = new Vector3[20];

    //StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("output.txt",true);
    void Start()
    {
        this.MoveToPoints();
        this.PrintPoints();
    }

    private void MoveToPoints()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
        {
            float timer = 0.0f;
            Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
            float x = this.RandomNum(timer);
            float y = this.RandomNum(x);
            float z = this.RandomNum(y);
            v[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);

            while (timer < movementDuration)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                float t = timer / movementDuration;
                t = t * t * t * (t * (6f * t - 15f) + 10f);
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, v[i], t);
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }

    void PrintPoints()
    {
        //path of file
        string path = Application.dataPath + "/Player.txt";
        //create file if nonexistent
        if(!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, "The player blob visited these random coordinates: \n\n");
        }

        foreach(Vector3 vector in v)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path, "(" + vector.x + ", " + vector.y + ", " + vector.z + ")\n\n");
        }


    }

    float RandomNum(float lastRandNum)
    {
        //Random value range can be changed in the future if necessary
        float randNum = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
        return System.Math.Abs(randNum - lastRandNum) < double.Epsilon ? RandomNum(randNum) : randNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the ball does not move at all utilizing just start.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    float movementDuration = 2.0f;
    WaitForSeconds waitBeforeMoving = new WaitForSeconds( 2f );
    Vector3[] path = new Vector3[20];

    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine( MainRoutine() );
    }

    IEnumerator MainRoutine ()
    {
        //generate new path:
        for( int i=0 ; i<path.Length ; i++ )
        {
            float timer = 0.0f;
            Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
            float x = RandomNum( timer );
            float y = RandomNum( x );
            float z = RandomNum( y );
            path[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }

        //traverse path:
        for( int i=0 ; i<path.Length ; i++ )
        {
            float timer = 0.0f;
            Vector3 startPos = transform.position;
            while( timer<movementDuration )
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                float t = timer / movementDuration;
                t = t * t * t * (t * (6f * t - 15f) + 10f);
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( startPos , path[i] , t );
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return waitBeforeMoving;
        }

        //print path:
        PrintPoints();
    }

    void PrintPoints ()
    {
        string filepath = Application.dataPath + "/Player.txt";
        if( File.Exists( filepath )==false )
        {
            File.WriteAllText( filepath , "The player blob visited these random coordinates: \n\n" );
        }
        foreach( Vector3 vector in path )
        {
            File.AppendAllText( filepath , $"{ JsonUtility.ToJson(vector) }\n\n" );
        }
    }

    float RandomNum ( float lastRandNum )
    {
        //Random value range can be changed in the future if necessary
        float randNum = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
        return System.Math.Abs(randNum - lastRandNum) < float.Epsilon ? RandomNum(randNum) : randNum;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for commenting!
Unfortunately, Unity complains that the AppendAlText line with Json "Assets/PlayerController.cs(60,43): error CS1644: Feature `interpolated strings' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification"

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it! Thank you so much for your help! :)